# ISAPI_Rewrite and asp.net events upon postback

Tags: htaccess, asp.net

I have a rewrite rule to rewrite `www.mysite.com/default.aspx` to `www.mysite.com`.

```
RewriteRule ^default.aspx$ / [NC,R=301,L]
```

On that site i have an asp.net server `Button`. When i click the button it tries to go to postback to `default.aspx`, but gets `301`'d to the root. This prevents the button's click event from triggering.

How can i redirect `default.aspx`, without breaking my button's event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$` just before rewrite rule to redirect only on GET requests:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$
RewriteRule ^default.aspx$ / [NC,R=301,L]
```

This will allow to POST to `default.aspx` .. but then it will not be redirected at all.

Ideally you would need to fix your server side / HTML: look at your `<form action"XXX">` -- change action to `/` instead of `default.aspx` (**P.S.** I'm not familiar with ASP.NET much and cannot 100% that this is how .NET really works, but this is the way how you can fix it if it would be PHP, for example). The idea is -- fix the source of the problem -- so the form gets submitted to `/` in first place.